# How can I use GDAL installed with QGIS from command line?

Tags: qgis, gdal, ogr, windows

I have QGIS 3.10 and I can run GDAL using OSGeo Shell. I want to be able to use GDAL commands from command line. For now, when I run `gdalinfo --version` I get message `'gdalinfo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

How can I fix this?

Comment: OSGeo4W shell is command line. Why don't you just use that?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the full path

```
"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\bin\"gdalinfo.exe --version
```

or just browse to the directory and call the tools

```
cd "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\bin\"
gdalinfo.exe --version
```

or put QGIS `bin` dir in your `path`.

Comment: Thanks, I set QGIS bin to path variable.